# Famo.us View can't contain imagesurface on top of a surface inside a scrollview

Tags: javascript, famo.us

```
define(function(require, exports, module){
var View            = require('src/core/View');
var Surface         = require('src/core/Surface');
var ImageSurface    = require('src/surfaces/ImageSurface');
var EventHandler    = require('src/core/EventHandler');
var StateModifier   = require('src/modifiers/StateModifier');
var RenderNode      = require('src/core/RenderNode');
var Transform       = require('src/core/Transform')

function DetailedList(){
    View.apply(this, arguments);

    _createStrips.call(this);
    _createImage.call(this);
}

DetailedList.prototype = Object.create(View.prototype);
DetailedList.prototype.constructor = DetailedList;
DetailedList.DEFAULT_OPTIONS = {
    height: 80,
    width: undefined,
    image: '',
    content: ''
} 

function _createStrips(){
    var backgroundSurface = new Surface({
        size: [this.options.width, this.options.height],
        properties: {
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            padding: '10px 15px',
            borderBottom: '1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',
            marginBottom: '5px'
        },
        content: this.options.content
    });
    var bgMod = new StateModifier({
        transform: Transform.behind
    })
    backgroundSurface.pipe(this._eventOutput);

    var node = new RenderNode(bgMod);
    node.add(backgroundSurface);
    this.add(node);

}

function _createImage(){
    var previewImage = new ImageSurface({
        size: [50, 50],
        content: this.options.image
    });

    var previewMod = new StateModifier({
        origin: [0.5, 0.5],
        align : [0, 0.5]
    });

    previewImage.pipe(this._eventOutput);

    var node = new RenderNode(previewMod);
    node.add(previewImage);
    this.add(node);
}


module.exports = DetailedList;});
```

This returns a view with a background surface and an image on top of it. I am using this as an item in a list. Without the image surface, it would scroll fine. But when I add the image, only the first item appears. Also, the image is outside the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explaination of issue:

The `DetailedList` `View` has no constraints in size and is being sized to the context of the `Scrollview`. Adding a `rootNode` to the view and setting it's size will constrain the items to that node's size.

```js
define('DetailedList', function(require, exports, module) {
  var View = require('famous/core/View');
  var Surface = require('famous/core/Surface');
  var ImageSurface = require('famous/surfaces/ImageSurface');
  var EventHandler = require('famous/core/EventHandler');
  var StateModifier = require('famous/modifiers/StateModifier');
  var Modifier = require('famous/core/Modifier');
  var RenderNode = require('famous/core/RenderNode');
  var Transform = require('famous/core/Transform');

  function DetailedList() {
    View.apply(this, arguments);

    this.rootNode = this.add(new Modifier({
      size: [this.options.width, this.options.height]
    }));

    _createStrips.call(this);
    _createImage.call(this);
  }

  DetailedList.prototype = Object.create(View.prototype);
  DetailedList.prototype.constructor = DetailedList;
  DetailedList.DEFAULT_OPTIONS = {
    height: 80,
    width: undefined,
    image: '',
    content: ''
  };

  function _createStrips() {
    var backgroundSurface = new Surface({
      size: [this.options.width, this.options.height - 1],
      properties: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        padding: '10px 65px',
        borderBottom: '1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1)'
      },
      content: this.options.content
    });
    var bgMod = new StateModifier({
      transform: Transform.behind
    });
    backgroundSurface.pipe(this._eventOutput);

    var node = new RenderNode(bgMod);
    node.add(backgroundSurface);
    this.rootNode.add(node);

  }

  function _createImage() {
    var previewImage = new ImageSurface({
      size: [50, 50],
      content: this.options.image
    });

    var previewMod = new StateModifier({
      origin: [0, 0.5],
      align: [0, 0.5]
    });

    previewImage.pipe(this._eventOutput);

    var node = new RenderNode(previewMod);
    node.add(previewImage);
    this.rootNode.add(node);
  }


  module.exports = DetailedList;
});
```

#### Note:

Using padding and margin needs to be taken into consideration when using on child nodes. The margin area will not fire an event, so best to reconsider using  margin.

#### Example Snippet:

```js
define('main', function(require, exports, module) {
  var Engine = require('famous/core/Engine');
  var OptionsManager = require('famous/core/OptionsManager');
  var Surface = require('famous/core/Surface');
  var Modifier = require('famous/core/Modifier');
  var RenderNode = require('famous/core/RenderNode');
  var Transform = require('famous/core/Transform');
  var ScrollView = require('famous/views/Scrollview');

  var DetailedList = require('DetailedList');

  var mainContext = Engine.createContext();
  mainContext.setPerspective(1000);

  var dl = new DetailedList({
    height: 75,
    content: 'Famo.us Application',
    image: 'http://code.famo.us/assets/famous_logo.svg'
  });

  var surfaces = [];
  var scrollview = new ScrollView();

  var counter = 0;

  _getView = function(i) {
    var cview = new DetailedList({
      height: 75,
      content: 'Custom View - ' + i,
      image: 'http://code.famo.us/assets/famous_logo.svg'
    });

    cview.pipe(scrollview);

    return cview;
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    var view = _getView(i);
    surfaces.push(view);
  }

  scrollview.sequenceFrom(surfaces);

  mainContext.add(new Modifier({
    align: [0, 0],
    origin: [0, 0]
  })).add(scrollview);

});

require(['main']);

define('DetailedList', function(require, exports, module) {
  var View = require('famous/core/View');
  var Surface = require('famous/core/Surface');
  var ImageSurface = require('famous/surfaces/ImageSurface');
  var EventHandler = require('famous/core/EventHandler');
  var StateModifier = require('famous/modifiers/StateModifier');
  var Modifier = require('famous/core/Modifier');
  var RenderNode = require('famous/core/RenderNode');
  var Transform = require('famous/core/Transform');

  function DetailedList() {
    View.apply(this, arguments);

    this.rootNode = this.add(new Modifier({
      size: [this.options.width, this.options.height]
    }));

    _createStrips.call(this);
    _createImage.call(this);
  }

  DetailedList.prototype = Object.create(View.prototype);
  DetailedList.prototype.constructor = DetailedList;
  DetailedList.DEFAULT_OPTIONS = {
    height: 80,
    width: undefined,
    image: '',
    content: ''
  };

  function _createStrips() {
    var backgroundSurface = new Surface({
      size: [this.options.width, this.options.height - 1],
      properties: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        padding: '10px 65px',
        borderBottom: '1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1)'
      },
      content: this.options.content
    });
    var bgMod = new StateModifier({
      transform: Transform.behind
    });
    backgroundSurface.pipe(this._eventOutput);

    var node = new RenderNode(bgMod);
    node.add(backgroundSurface);
    this.rootNode.add(node);

  }

  function _createImage() {
    var previewImage = new ImageSurface({
      size: [50, 50],
      content: this.options.image
    });

    var previewMod = new StateModifier({
      origin: [0, 0.5],
      align: [0, 0.5]
    });

    previewImage.pipe(this._eventOutput);

    var node = new RenderNode(previewMod);
    node.add(previewImage);
    this.rootNode.add(node);
  }


  module.exports = DetailedList;
});
```

```html
<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.16/minified/require.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.famo.us/lib/requestAnimationFrame.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.famo.us/lib/classList.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.famo.us/lib/functionPrototypeBind.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.famo.us/famous/0.3.5/famous.css" />
<script src="http://code.famo.us/famous/0.3.5/famous.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i found a problem after using your code. It doesn't scroll. After a few debugging, i found out that bgMod( the state modifier for the background surface, specifically the transform: Transform.behind line) is causing the problem. I've set the perspective but to no avail. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: When I run the snippet, it scrolls.  It is probably something in the app you are plugging it into. If you have a public repo or example, I can take a look at it if you want. Try removing the `behind` and try `Transform.translate(0,0,0.0001)` instead.